# React y three.js: No aparece mi modelo gltf que estoy carganda

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

Estoy haciendo una interfaz grafica y quiero que unos dados 3D aparezcan en la pagina, por ahora a ubicación es lo de menos , solo quiero algo del modelo. La cosa es que no veo absolutamente nada del modelo.

Ademas me aparece el siguiente error: Error al cargar modelo gltf Syntaxerror: JSON.parse

Probe ver el modelo en un visualizador online y si carga y todo

Adjunto imagen y codigo en el link[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Link del codigo: https://pastebin.com/Y8JeFX1i

Comment: Aparentemente el problema es del modelo. Intenta cargarlo [aquí](https://threejs.org/editor/) o en otro visor 3D para asegurarte de que no sea así.

Comment: Lo probe aqui y todo bien https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/